# Apache pig query

Tags: apache-pig

If you carefully examine the monthly data sets for 2013, you will find each row contains information pertaining to variables such as State-Code, Year, Month, Day, Precipitation Amount, etc.

On the average, which state has the highest amount of precipitation in September 2013?

I'm a new on the apache pig i got the error for parser i tried many times to do resolve but it's not working

This is my query for apache pig:

```
grunt>dataset=LOAD'home/bitnami/HDP/september.csv'using pigstorage(',')as (state:chararray,data_value:chararray);

substring_state=FOREACH SEPTEMBER GENERATE SUBSTRING ((State_code,4,5);
group_state=Group september by state;

order_data=order count_data by data_value desc;

limit=limit order _data 1;

dump limit;
```

I get the following parser error:

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It would be helpful to include the full error message your are receiving along with a sampling of the data you are trying to parse. Without those it would be very difficult for someone to provide a quality answer. Bonus, you should also formulate a specific question you would like answered.

Comment: On the average, which state has the highest amount of precipitation in September 2013? this is my question for apache pig query

Comment: If you carefully examine the monthly data sets for 2013, you will find each row contains information pertaining to variables such as State-Code, Year, Month, Day, Precipitation Amount, etc. this is the variables for the query